# how to preload images for javascript slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, image, preload

I wrote a simple JavaScript slideshow where the background is changed after some time via CSS background property. The problem is that on devices with low bandwidth the slideshow shows blank images when the images are not loaded. My solution would be to preload all images and start the slideshow when all images are loaded. How can I preload the images and use them as background?

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="jumbotron" style="width:200pt; height:200pt"></div>

    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="slideshow.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

slideshow.js:

```
$(window).on("load", function () {
  // List of image paths.
  var background_images = ["image1.jpg", "image2.jpg"]

  // Every X miliseconds change the background image.
  var X = 4000
  backgroundImageIdx = 0;
  window.setInterval(function () {
    $(".jumbotron").css("background-image", "url(" + background_images[backgroundImageIdx] + ")");
    backgroundImageIdx++;
    if (backgroundImageIdx >= nrOfBackgroundImages) {
      backgroundImageIdx = 0;
    }
  }, X);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To load images dynamically you could use a recursive function like in the following example, which takes an array of image paths and loads them, then adds them to the document body after the page has loaded. You can adapt the function to your own purpose, but the key is to pass index 0 at the start and then do whatever you need with the image inside your callback function, which receives a new array containing the images as your parameter.

Callback approach:

```
<script>
    let images = [
        'images/DSCF1589.jpg',
        'images/DSCF1590.jpg',
        'images/DSCF1591.jpg',
        'images/DSCF1592.jpg',
        'images/DSCF1593.jpg',
        'images/DSCF1594.jpg',
    ];

    // Loads the images one at a time, then calls the callback function when all images
    // have been loaded
    function loadImages(images, index, callback) {
        if (index < images.length) {
            let img = new Image();
            img.src = images[index];
            images[index] = img;
            images[index].onload = function() {
                loadImages(images, ++index, callback);
            };
        } else {
            callback(images);
        }
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        loadImages(images, 0, (images) => {
            // Your slideshow code goes here. This is just example code
            // of adding the images to your document once they are all loaded
            images.forEach((item) => {
               document.querySelector('body').appendChild(item);
            });
        });
    };
</script>
```

Promise approach:

```
<script>
    let images = [
        'images/DSCF1589.jpg',
        'images/DSCF1590.jpg',
        'images/DSCF1591.jpg',
        'images/DSCF1592.jpg',
        'images/DSCF1593.jpg',
        'images/DSCF1594.jpg',
    ];

    function loadImages(images) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            (function loadEach(images, index) {
                if (index < images.length) {
                    let img = new Image();
                    img.src = images[index];
                    images[index] = img;
                    images[index].onload = function() {
                        loadEach(images, ++index);
                    };
                    images[index].onerror = (err) => reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(images);
                }
            })(images, 0)
        });
    }
    window.onload = function() {
        loadImages(images).then((images) => {
            // Your slideshow code goes here. This is just example code
            // of adding the images to your document once they are all loaded
            images.forEach((item) => {
                document.querySelector('body').appendChild(item);
            });
        }).catch((err) => console.error(err));
    };
</script>
```

(**Note:** these methods replace the image url's in the array with the image themselves. If you wanted to keep both, you could use a map to store url/Image pairs)